# How can I make LastPass trust a device for more than 30 days?

Tags: multi-factor-auth, lastpass

When two-factor authentication is enabled in LastPass, there is an option when logging in to trust my current device for 30 days:

[image: LastPass asking to re verify after 30 days]

I appreciate the security benefit of two-factor authentication, but having to re authenticate each month feels a bit excessive. The only solution I could find was disabling two-factor entirely, which is something I would like to avoid.

[The LastPass Blog](https://blog.lastpass.com/2015/11/new-in-security-expiring-trusted-devices-after-30-days.html/) claims that there used to be an option to disable trusted device expiration in Account Settings, but this option seems to have gone missing after the [LastPass 4.0 redesign](https://lastpass.com/lastpassfour/).

Is there a way to make LastPass trust my device for more than 30 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trusted devices expiring after 30 days can be disabled in Advanced Settings.

1. Login to LastPass.
2. Open your LastPass Vault.
3. Open **Account Settings**.

   [image: Account Settings button]
4. Select **Show Advanced Settings**.
5. Scroll down and select **Skip 30 day expiration for trusted clients**.

   [image: Skip 30 day expiration for trusted clients]
6. Click **Update**.
7. Enter your account password and press **Confirm**.

Comment: Very helpful. Odd that they don't have a timeout. I would love to have it be every year or something. Thanks!

Comment: This feature isn't available, or is no longer available. I'm running version 4.9 (on MacOS Mojave) and don't see the option. Too bad, I'd like to turn off the 30-day expiration without losing 2FA altogether.